# Plot trackers for defects in vector field

Tags: plotting, vector

I plot some defect configurations like these

[image]

and I would like to be able to add some trackers on top of them, similar to these:

[image]

A much simpler working example of the first picture can be produced with the code:

```
L = 2;
\[Rho][x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
\[CapitalTheta][x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];
rp2 = Graphics[{Red, Thickness[0.005], Dashed, Circle[{0, 0}, 1]}];
Show[{VectorPlot[{Cos[\[CapitalTheta][x, y]/2], 
Sin[\[CapitalTheta][x, y]/2]}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 
VectorStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[3], Arrowheads[0]}}, 
VectorScale -> Tiny, VectorPoints -> 20], rp2}]
```

Comment: The function that you give `VectorPlot` represents velocity, if you integrate velocity you get position.  So what you have to do is use `NDSolve` to integrate the velocity given a starting point $(x_0, y_0)$. Then you can use the solution to plot points on the trajectory. There could also be simpler ways, for example by identifying line segments in the resulting graphics object and using that, but it's unclear if it would actually be simpler.

Comment: @C.E. In fact, I am more interested in the shape dashed lines, I already have a way of tracking the centre of the defects. Any ideas on how to obtain those sketch-like profiles?

Comment: I was talking about the dashed lines, I thought those profiles were parts of trajectories.

Comment: Yes, they are. I can actually plot the trajectories as streamlines in `VectorPlot` or `StreamPlot`, but how do I make them thicker and a different colour in specific regions?

Comment: Well, you do what I suggested in my first comment and then when you've sampled the trajectory in the way you want you use `Graphics` with `Line` to create your line. Then you use `Show` to combine the line and the `VectorPlot`. You can use `Thick` or `Thickness` and `Dashed` with colors to get the look in the image, I think.